# special characters jquery load

Tags: php, jquery, special-characters

How would you submit special characters though jquery load function and recieve them on the php side?

`$('#DIV').load('page.php?type=' + type)`

And

On page.php `$type = $_GET['type']`

Where 'type' is a word with values such as 'é'.

Cheers.

Comment: The question is what encoding `type` is in, where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method.
Use either .get or .ajax methods. Like so:

```
var data = {
      type: 'anything really'
   };
$.get(url, data, callback);
```

You can also use $.ajax. It has a similar syntax but provides more options. These methods automatically escape your data so you don't really have to worry about that.